# Choose a textbox based on value of int value

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

So I have a program that has 81 textboxes(I know that sounds wild, but they are in a grid), and I need to be able to edit each textbox based on the value of an int. My textboxes are named textBox1 - textBox81. I also need to have the counting up value of i there for every textbox that has a name that starts with "textBox" then 1-81. I will have other textboxs not named like this, and I want them not to be accounted for in this.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
{
   textBoxVALUEOFi.Text = "SomeValue";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How abut this...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
{
    Control ctrl = this.Controls["tbx"+i];
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
{    
     this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true) = "SomeValue";
}
```

Or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
{
     this.Controls["textBox" + i] = "SomeValue";
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, and I wrote my question a bit badly. I meant they are in a grid, but still in the form. They are just arranged like a grid, but not in a parent control that is a grid. They are children of form1.

Comment: then just replace `grid1` with `this` .

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do something like this

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (x is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)x).Text = "SomeValue";
    }
}
```

or you can also try

```
foreach(TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
{
    tb.Text = "SomeValue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 81; i++)
{    
     Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true)[0].Text = "SomeValue";
}
```